# Search sql database for a column name, then search for a value within the retuned columns

Tags: sql, search

This query will search a database for a specific column name.  I would like to go one step further and search the returned columns for a specific value.

```
SELECT t.name AS table_name,
SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS schema_name,
c.name AS column_name,
FROM sys.tables AS t
INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID
WHERE c.name LIKE '%Example%'
```

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not such system table present for this kind of searching. Whereas you can try this for your purpose

```
DECLARE @ValueToSearch NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @SearchColumn NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @ColumnName NVARCHAR(200)
SET @ValueToSearch ='YOUR VALUE TP SEARCH'
SET @SearchColumn = 'YOUR COLUMN'
DECLARE @getResult CURSOR
SET @getResult = CURSOR FOR
    SELECT t.name AS table_name,c.name AS column_name FROM sys.tables AS t INNER JOIN     sys.columns c ON t.OBJECT_ID = c.OBJECT_ID WHERE c.name = @SearchColumn
    OPEN @getResult
    FETCH NEXT FROM @getResult INTO @TableName,@ColumnName
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON ;
        DECLARE @RESULT INT; 
        DECLARE @TYPE INT
        DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(1000)
        SET @QUERY = 'select @RESULT=count(*) from ' + ISNULL(@TableName,'') +'     WHERE '+ ISNULL(@ColumnName,'')+'='''+ ISNULL(@ValueToSearch,'') +''''
        EXEC sp_executesql @QUERY,
            N'@result int OUTPUT, @type int OUTPUT',
            @RESULT OUTPUT, 
            @TYPE OUTPUT
        IF(ISNULL(@RESULT,0)>0)
        BEGIN
            SET NOCOUNT ON;
        SELECT ' COLUMN '+ @ColumnName + ' OF TABLE ' +@TableName+ ' HAS     THIS VALUE.'
        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM @getResult INTO @TableName,@ColumnName
    END
CLOSE @getResult
DEALLOCATE @getResult
```

Thanks

Manoj

Comment: Thanks so much Manoj.  This is much quicker!  Do you know how I would return the results to a single set?

Comment: Well, you can use any temp table or table variable for the purpose.

Answer (score 3):

For example, I have a database named **Organisation**. I have more than one table where **tax_id** column is present.

Most of the time, we have to find such a column from the whole database. 
**The solution is provided below:**

```
select table_name,column_name from information_schema.columns
where column_name like '%tax%'
```

There is no matter in query to database name which ever you just need to change willing **Column Name** and will found required result

**Search any value Like computer in whole database in which column and in which tables value computer exists**

For it first we need to write a store procedure then we reuse it for our search i got it from http://vyaskn.tripod.com/search_all_columns_in_all_tables.htm very perfect result.
after executing store procedure we got required result as in given below image.
Image showing complete search result of keyword computer from whole database.
[image: Image showing complete search result of keyword computer from whole database]

**Above was concept to solve it.Exact Query fullfilling above requirment is below**

```
Select tax_id from (select table_name from information_schema.columns
where column_name = 'tax_id') as temp
```

Comment: Thanx @rizwan, Rizwan rocks. :-) ;-)