# Find on what database a particular row is

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple database with the same schema. All the databases have A table called `Invoices`. The Id of that table is a GUID therefore there are no duplicates.

Anyways lets say I have Db1, Db2, ... Dbx .  **I want to know on what database is invoice with ID = "XF4G-XF78-2156-7XH8"**

How can I do a foreach statement and exit the loop once I find the database that contains that invoice?

Comment: You some scripting language to achieve this - bash, php, powershell

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362695/search-sql-database-for-a-column-name-then-search-for-a-value-within-the-retune

Comment: RDBMS vendor and version? It is posible with MySQL...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000)
DECLARE @lookup NVARCHAR(20) = 'XF4G-XF78-2156-7XH8'

SET @sql = 'IF OBJECT_ID(''[?].dbo.Invoices'') IS NOT NULL SELECT ''?'' FROM [?].dbo.Invoices WHERE ID=''' + @Lookup + ''''

EXEC dbo.sp_MsForEachDb @sql
```

How's that?  Dbo is the assumed owner.  Change to the correct owner if this is wrong.

### Edit

Thanks to your answer I did this works great!

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000)

SET @sql = '
IF OBJECT_ID(''[?].dbo.Invoices'') IS NOT NULL
begin
    declare @query NVARCHAR(255)
    Select @query = (Select [Id] from [?].dbo.Invoices where [Id] = 'XF4G-XF78-2156-7XH8'') 
    IF @query IS NOT NULL
    begin
          print ''Database = '' + ''?''         
    end
end
'
EXEC dbo.sp_MsForEachDb @sql
```

Now I know to what database the invoice belongs!

Comment: +1 Thanks it works great. But once I found the record how do I know from what database it was?