# How can I search the entire SQL database for a specific column name, and then search only those columns for a specific value?

Tags: sql

At work, we use an absolutely massive database with multiple different programs writing to the main bucket. Unfortunately, there's not always a good way to know from those individual programs where specific data points might be written to the database. I have a query that can search everything for a specific value or string, but because of the size of the database, it usually takes about 7 hours to complete.

I thought that if I could narrow the search a bit, I might be able to speed that up. A lot of the values I often have to look up would be under similarly named columns (i.e. "UserName", "UserID", etc.) Is there a good way to do a search that looks through all of my tables for a specific column name, and then searches only those columns for the value that I'm trying to locate?

I found a similar question asked a few years back

[Search sql database for a column name, then search for a value within the retuned columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17362695/search-sql-database-for-a-column-name-then-search-for-a-value-within-the-retune/17363526#17363526?newreg=60d4b0ef5e9745dab1333dcb6761f5a7)

but when I run the answer, all it returns is "Command(s) completed successfully."

I'm still a little green at this, so I'm not discounting the fact that it could be a PICNIC issue on my end.

Comment: Did you modify the query input (`@SearchColumn` and `@ValueToSearch`) to a known column name and value so you can be sure it should have returned something?

Comment: Yes, I've done exactly that (tested known columns and cell values). The report continues to return the same quoted response.